# shoulda-matches error when using model setters before validarion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda

I have the Order model with the line for calculating total total price of products the user is ordering

```
before_validation :set_total!
validates :total, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
```

set_total looks like this

```
def set_total!
  self.total = products.map(&price).sum
end
```

On my specs I am trying to check if the total validations are implemented **TDD**

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:total) }
it { should validate_numericality_of(:total).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(0) }
```

Unfortunately I am receiving the following error

> Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:total) }
>
> ```
>    Order did not properly validate that :total cannot be empty/falsy.
>      After setting :total to ‹nil› -- which was read back as
>      ‹#<BigDecimal:5634b8b81008,'0.0',9(27)>› -- the matcher expected the
>      Order to be invalid, but it was valid instead.
>
>      As indicated in the message above, :total seems to be changing certain
>      values as they are set, and this could have something to do with why
>      this test is failing. If you've overridden the writer method for this
>      attribute, then you may need to change it to make this test pass, or
>      do something else entirely.
> ```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `validate_presence_of` matcher is roughly equivalent to writing this test by hand:

```
describe Order do
  it "fails validation when total is nil" do
    order = Order.new
    order.total = nil
    order.validate
    expect(order.errors[:total]).to include("can't be blank")
    order.total = 42
    expect(order.errors[:total]).not_to include("can't be blank")
  end
end
```

If you were to run this test, you would find that this would fail. Why? Because in your model, you set `total` to a non-nil value when validations are performed. That's why you're getting this error.

So you don't really need the validation or the matcher, since neither one would fail.